# Dividing screen into two equal parts , can not set layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I guess question is silly, but I am missing something in this and want to understand.

I am dividing the screen into two equal parts. I know this can be done by setting weight. But I do not know why I can not set weight in Linear layout. Instead I am setting weightSum, but what I understood about weightSum is, it is space on screen left after setting width and height I guess.

here is what I am doing

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_panel">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/top"
android:weightSum="100">
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:weightSum="50"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/ bottom">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PS: I cannot set layout_weight property using android lollipop

Comment: which two parts you want? one side listview and what you want another side?

Comment: First linerlayout with listview and second linearlayout containing framelayout

Comment: Check my answer below, it will work.

Comment: Use linearLayout instead Relative and u can use weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_panel">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/top"
>
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/ bottom">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no, but why did you give width 0dp, and I need both vertically so if i set orienattion to vertical, I can not set 0dp for height

Comment: @user2323 You want this vertically or Horizontally? I did it for horizontally. Please mention proper.

Comment: sorry i did not mention , I want vertical but to make it vertical, I only need to set orientation and set height to 0dp...am I correct here?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/color_in_palette"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CCFFFF"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:textSize="0sp" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50">  
    
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/color_id"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:text="(204,255,255)"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
          
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:numColumns="13"
        android:layout_weight="48" >
    </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
  

  </LinearLayout>
```

In this button will occupy the half of the screen , and the other half is occupied by another Linear Layout , which contains a TextView & GridView

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You cant add a `weightSum` within a Relative layout that it is only bounded to linearlayout layout params itself.

**solution:**

add another linearlayout inside your relatie layout as a parent to both of the inner linear layout.

**sample:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_panel">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/top"
android:weightSum="0.5">
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"
    android:weightSum="0.5"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/ bottom">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is not dividing, only top part is visible

Answer (score 0):

Weightsum  is property used by parent to find the total weight sum by its children.This property is only applicable to [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum). Its childrens should specify its weight with width or height as 0dp. You can find the tutorial [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-2/). So your layout.xml will be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/drag_line"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get Root attribute always be <Relative> and with in that write your remaining XML code.

e.g.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

//Replace above XML code by...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
          >



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/black">

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```